# how to display comparison chart using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, database, charts

I am trying to display ajax bar chart in my web page. But it is only displaying one value .
My db contains 3 columns(name, credit, debit) I want to display the credit debit values in chart. But the chart is only displaying one value. How can I modify the given below coding. Thank you.

Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string query = "select Name from aTable";
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);
            ddlCountries.DataSource = dt;
            ddlCountries.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlCountries.DataValueField = "Name";
            ddlCountries.DataBind();
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
        }
    }
    private DataTable GetData(string query, SqlParameter[] prms = null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                if (prms != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
    protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select Name, Debit, Credit From aTable where Name=@Name";
        SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
        prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        prms[0].Value = ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        DataTable dt = GetData(query, prms);

        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }
        BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y });
        BarChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);
        BarChart1.ChartTitle = string.Format("{0} -RunTimeReportChart", ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value);
        if (x.Length > 3)
        {
            BarChart1.ChartWidth = (x.Length * 100).ToString();
        }
        BarChart1.Visible = ddlCountries.SelectedItem.Value != "";

    }
```

Data Base:

[image]

Actual Output:
The given below chart is only displaying the name and debit value. I want to display the credit value also. Please help me. 
[image]

Comment: `decimal[] z = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
z[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][2]);
BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = z });`

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: @Thirisangu : Actually there is no error I have. As a beginner in asp.net so some confusions. Now it works fine. Thank you again.

Comment: If it works for you, accept this an answer. It may help someone in future.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like :

```
decimal[] z = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
z[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][2]);
BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = z });
```